# How to obtain the number of downstream build from job which triggers it?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a job (let's call it A) which in some step triggers its downstream jobs (let's call it B and C). I will turn on the python script in job A in post-build, and want to have in it the number of build of B and C triggered by job A. Can take it by an argument to script, or some other way if possible. How to do it?

I thought about obtaining it from console output from A and using regexes, but want to avoid it. I can't see the option in Jenkins API which can help.

Comment: Maybe you need a proper workflow manager like snakemake or ruffus

Comment: Is job A the only one that can trigger the others jobs ? Logging each trigger in job A coud be an option, it's not that bad. You could also compare build numbers of B and C before and after, you'll have the diff

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel yes, A is the only one that triggers these jobs. What do you mean by logging trigger in job A? It looks like the good option.

Comment: Are you using a JenkinsFile ? If so, a simple `echo` will do the stuff. Otherwise, look at a message like `Triggering a new build of ..`  in the logs